# LUIS recognition of pre-built entities degrades with time?

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

training a LUIS model, we are baffled. At first, no recognition happens for simple datetime entities. Then, waiting a couple of hours, recognition is good. 15 hours later, all is broken again!!

see pictures
1. first:
[image: right after training]
2. few hours later:
[image]
3. now, 15 hours later after addition a few more New utterances
[image]

whats going on??

Comment: UPDATE: signing in and out solved this - for now. But I'm still not assured

Comment: This has nothing to do with signing in and out. I think you should send this to LUIS support so that they can check the issue.

Comment: LUIS support confirmed this is their bug

Comment: @Lior Do you have a confirmation if this is fixed already?

Comment: @TarunGehlaut sorry for the delay, yes, confirmed